# Expose view children as content children to parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-components

How do I expose a component's `ViewChildren` to a parent component as `ContentChildren`?

Say I have a component, `MatSelect`, that [looks for `ContentChildren` like this](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/9eeb4b5aa0473c0815a73bfe3c2ed6164d86a3b3/src/material/select/select.ts#L346):

```js
@ContentChildren(MatOption, { descendants: true }) options: QueryList<MatOption>;
```

If I use this component as follows:

```html
<mat-select>
  <mat-option>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

it will detect the `mat-option` element as a content child.

Now if I create a component that generates these options, say `OptionGeneratorComponent`, with a template as follows:

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
  {{option.viewValue}}
</mat-option>
```

Then I use this component as content for the previously mentioned `MatSelect` component like this:

```html
<mat-select>
  <option-generator> <!-- option-generator instead of mat-option -->
  </option-generator>
</mat-select>
```

the `MatSelect` component doesn't detect the `mat-option` elements generated by the `OptionGenerator` element.

How do I make the `MatSelect` component detect the `MatOption` components I generated with `OptionGeneratorComponent` as content children.

[In this other demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-content-children) I'm trying to find the `Pane` elements generated by `PaneGeneratorComponent` with the `@ContentChildren` property in `TabComponent`. It detects the `Pane` elements that are hard coded but not the ones generated by the `PaneGenerator`.

I have some more information and a demo about my exact use case in [a question I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826432/angular-material-select-doesnt-detect-changes-to-options-generated-by-nested-co).